# Robot Framework: I got [Errno 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed after try to run Robot script for automate test Mainframe

Tags: robotframework, mainframe

I got the error: [Errno 10057] after I try to run Robot script for automate test Mainframe.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Mainframe3270    

*** Test Cases ***       
Example
   Open Connection    HostTest
   Change Wait Time    0.9
   Set Screenshot Folder    C:\\Temp\\IMG
   ${value}    Read    2    13    10
   Take Screenshot
   Close Connection
```

error: [Errno 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

I don't know what something wrong in my Robot code or configuration, can anyone explain please. This is my first time to do the Robot in Mainframe.

Comment: It work now by input the wc3270 folder to C:\Program Files and set environment.